# How to nudge text to the right in div?

Tags: html, text, spacing, inline-code

I have a div with the a coloured background and white text that I can use as sub-titles throughout my page.

I'm using `line-height:1.8;` to center the text vertically (If there is a better way, please tell)

but the only problem I'm having is that the text is aligned left but I don't want it flush against the div, I want it about 5-10px to the right and methods I have tried are nudging the div over too, not just the text.

I don't want to use `&nbsp;` to nudge my text, I'm looking for a nicer way

Also I would prefer HTML and in-line CSS only.

```
<div id="title" style="width:300px; height:30px; background-color:#003777; line-height:1.8; color:#FFFFFF; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
Title
</div>
```

Heres a fiddle of my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/XrB2j/

Comment: use padding and margin

Comment: Want like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XrB2j/3/)?

Comment: @Bip I tried padding and margin before and it was affecting the whole Div.

Comment: @DKM ah yes! I was only doing padding, not padding-left. I tried margin-left but that didn't work

Comment: DKM's solutions works best